# REGEX: why '^([a-z] | a)$' does not match 'a'?

Tags: regex

I never used regular expressions before and I was testing some examples.
What I don't understand is why the regular expression `^([a-z] | a)$` doesn't match the string *'a'*.

As I understood `[a-z]` is equivalent to `(a | b | c | ... | y | z)`, so
`[a-z] | a`  must be equivalent to `(a | b | c | ... | y | z) | a`, that is the same
to say `(a | b | c | ... | y | z)` or `[a-z]`.

For that reason a string str matches `^([a-z] | a)$` iff matches `^[a-z]$`.

That's why I don't understand why that regular expression doesn't match string *'a'* or *'e'* for example.

PS: I was testing this in this [page](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: Because it matches any letter between 'a' and 'z' **+ space** or **space** + 'a'.

Comment: The whitespace around | is significant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spaces matter in regular expressions. Remove the spaces around the pipe (`|`) and it should work.